# How can I find the Number of delay, active, idle sessions in teradata for past 1 week?

Tags: teradata

i am looking to analyse if there is a way to find the session counts in active, idle, delay queue in Teradata

Count of session by session state by day by hour

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Session state is point-in-time. What does "by hour" mean? One snapshot "on the hour"?